# How to install exe via the wixsharp installer

Tags: c#, windows, wix, windows-installer, wixsharp

My question is not necessarily on wixsharp but may you know to help. Like, maybe i'm using the wrong project type etc.

Im using `ManagedProject` of wix sharp.

During the my installer I'd like to install *.net sdk* which actually is an exe file.

I have the file attached to the project, so i just run a process on `AfterInstall` action that install the file.

Now, the exe file behaves like msi installer, double click opens GUI etc.

The issue is, that It's failed with error code `1618` which means it can't run multiple programs in parallel.

*a.k.a my installer and the exe file.*

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer (.MSI) has a mutex that prevents two MSIs from changing the machine state concurrently.  You need to create a bootstrapper/chainer (.EXE) that installs the .NET SDK (which is a bootstrapper/chainer .EXE that internally contains one or more .MSIs) sequentially to get around this design constraint.

Feel free to contact me and I can assist you in doing this while we update an open source repos that I maintain for the .SDK that you need.